# Sintaxis JS - ¿Qué es esto?

Tags: javascript

```
const cc = [
    {
        'colors': {
            'options': ['black', 'grey', 'pink']
        }
    }
];
```

¿Alguien puede explicarme que es esto?

Answer (score 2):

Es un `array` con un único objeto que a su vez contiene una propiedad (`colors`) que tiene una propiedad `options` que es un `array` de `strings`.

Como ves en este ejemplo los arrays también son un objeto:

```js
const cc = [
    {
        'colors': {
            'options': ['black', 'grey', 'pink']
        }
    }
];

console.log(`Type of cc: ${typeof cc} - IsArray? ${Array.isArray(cc)}`);
console.log(`Type of cc[0]: ${typeof cc[0]} - IsArray? ${Array.isArray(cc[0])}`);
console.log(`Type of cc[0].colors: ${typeof cc[0].colors} - IsArray? ${Array.isArray(cc[0].colors)}`);
console.log(`Type of cc[0].colors.options: ${typeof cc[0].colors.options} - IsArray? ${Array.isArray(cc[0].colors.options)}`);
```

¿Qué es lo que no entiendes exactamente?

Comment: Lo entiendo como has dicho que es, pero se me hace muy extraña este tipo de estructura: arrays con objetos dentro, que a su vez pueden tener otros arrays... etc. Gracias por la explicación, un saludo.

Comment: A lo que has dicho @Orici, imaginate un Array de personas (hay muchas personas) cada persona (cada objeto) tiene un monedero (otro objeto) y dentro del monedero tiene muchas cosas (un array) ...

Comment: ¿Extraña? No te creas, yo he visto auténticas montañas de objetos con arrays de objetos dentro.